# ffmpeg wasm - how to take client-side created mp4 and upload it to the same server hosting the index/js files being used

Tags: javascript, html, video, ffmpeg, webassembly

Ok, so Im an IT guy and kind of a noob on the dev side of the fence. But I've been able to create this ffmpeg wasm page that takes a canvas and converts it to webm / and .mp4 -- what i WANT to do is take the resulting .mp4 file and upload it to the server where the page/js are being served from. is this possible? I will include my source code which is fairly simple and straight forward, I just don't know how to manipulate the resulting mp4 file that ffmpeg spits out (i realize it is happening client side) to be able to push it up to the server (maybe with aupload.php type situation?) the solution can be html/java/php whatever, so long as it takes the mp4 output and gets it onto the server. I'd VERY MUCH appreciate a hand here.

Going to try my best to properly insert the html and js. please bear with me if i've done something wrong, i've never had to -ask- a question on here, usually just look up existing answers.

```js
const { createFFmpeg } = FFmpeg;
const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({
  log: true
});

const transcode = async (webcamData) => {
  const message = document.getElementById('message');
  const name = 'record.webm';
  await ffmpeg.load();
  message.innerHTML = 'Start transcoding';
  await ffmpeg.write(name, webcamData);
  await ffmpeg.transcode(name,  'output.mp4');
  message.innerHTML = 'Complete transcoding';
  const data = ffmpeg.read('output.mp4');

  const video = document.getElementById('output-video');
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' }));
  dl.href = video.src;
  dl.innerHTML = "download mp4"
}

fn().then(async ({url, blob})=>{
    transcode(new Uint8Array(await (blob).arrayBuffer()));
})

function fn() {
var recordedChunks = [];

var time = 0;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
    var stream = canvas.captureStream(60);

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9"
    });

    mediaRecorder.start(time);

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
        recordedChunks.push(event.data);
        // for demo, removed stop() call to capture more than one frame
    }

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function (event) {
        var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
            "type": "video/webm"
        });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        res({url, blob}); // resolve both blob and url in an object

        myVideo.src = url;
        // removed data url conversion for brevity
    }

// for demo, draw random lines and then stop recording
var i = 0,
tid = setInterval(()=>{
  if(i++ > 20) { // draw 20 lines
    clearInterval(tid);
    mediaRecorder.stop();
  }
  let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  let cx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.strokeStyle = 'green';
  cx.moveTo(Math.random()*100, Math.random()*100);
  cx.lineTo(Math.random()*100, Math.random()*100);
  cx.stroke();
},200)

});
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.8.1/dist/ffmpeg.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="canvas2mp4.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
here is a canvas<br>
<canvas id="canvas" style="height:100px;width:100px"></canvas><br>

here is a recorded video of the canvas in webM format<br>
<video id="myVideo" controls="controls"></video><br>


here is a transcoded mp4 from the webm above CLIENT SIDE using ffmpeg<br>
<video id="output-video" controls="controls"></video><br>
<a id="dl" href="" download="download.mp4"></a>
<div id="message"></div><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As long as your server has a POST handler for the same url, then sure. So: what server is this running on?

Comment: hi mike, thanks for the quick reply.. its for a client who plans to put it on a VPS... that being said -i made delivery of this initial prototype he gave me ration of bs about "wheres the php"  naturally i was confused since this was a solution that was to be implemented into his own project yet he doesn't know how to do it.. i guess my question is - can we create a "save to server" button that will just fire off a post and drop the url to "uploads/someName.mp4" ? can the php be inline? (no need for a success page or anything) - sorry if any of these questions are foolish i'm out of my element

Comment: also, again, likely a n00b question, but where in my amateur-ish code could i set the framerate on the .mp4 that ffmpeg makes to 10 fps? (im familiar running it from the command line for many many years, just not sure where in the code I could put that so all mp4s output to the spec he asked for (and he can easily change it) -- heres the git i created if thats helpful -- https://github.com/itzfarrell/drtom

Comment: Do you have a link to the FFmpeg/JS tool that you're using? The docs might have a clue... Normally in CLI version of FFmpeg it is enough to use `-` as an output filename to receive the bytes back into some Array. This only works if your own app runs FFmpeg as a **process** (JS does not run external apps).

Comment: its in the git link above. its the ffmpeg js/wasm